# How to split the entire panel, and not just one tab of the panel?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to make my Debugger call stack appear in the panel at the bottom.  But I want it to *always* be visible, regardless of which tab I have selected in the panel.  In other words, I want to divide the panel into two regions.  One (on the left) with the callstack, and another (on the right) with Problems, Output, Debug Console, etc.

Presently, when I drop my Call Stack onto the Panel, it adds it as another tab.  If instead I drag it to the left side of the Panel, the highlight appears that it will do the right thing, but it instead adds it as a panel *inside* of the tab.

Is there any way (extensions are ok) that will allow me to have more control over how the panel is laid out to support this use case?